# Hudson CI & Project dependecies

Tags: hudson, build-automation

Can Hudson CI tool solve project dependencies others than trivial ones?
For example, how can I set up scenario in which there are two independent modules (A, B) and module C dependent on A and B?

There's no way in my opinion:

- "Build others project" doesn't guarantee that A, B are built before C
- "Build after other projects are built" guarantee only "C is triggered after A *or* B" (A *and* B needed)
- Join plugin can solve this if one has ~ 3 modules. If there are modules A1, ....., A100 and C1, ....., C100 then it is supposed to write 100 additional Join triggers and issue 100 additional rebuilds of B (in other words, every B's reverse dependency needs rebuild of B). So in case that Join triggers cannot be trivially XML hacked and nonsense rebuilds of unchanged B cannot be skipped (is this possible?) it is unpractical.

So is there some way or some standard workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but your second option ought to work:

Build after other projects are built" guarantee only "C is triggered after A or B" (A and B needed)

This means that C will be built every time there are changes to either A or B.  If A and B are truly independent of each other as you say, that satisfies all the dependencies.

Comment: Yes, you're right. If one SUPPOSES that A and B has been already build than every change to A triggers C's build, every B's change triggers C's build and in case of change to A and B there is C rebuilt for two times.

Comment: Yes, you're right. If one SUPPOSES that A and B has been already build than every change to A triggers C's build, every B's change triggers C's build and in case of change to A and B there is C rebuilt (likely) for two times.
However, my paradigm was quite different, I haven't supposed these "incremental" builds. Rather I'm supposing build-server which obtains from time to time build-request (say one per 1-2 week(s)) and make whole system from ground up.
I think I have to rethought these two cases....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try using the [Ivy](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Ivy+Plugin) plugin, which uses [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy) to manage dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but in my opinion this is adding one more trouble (Ivy), maybe two (Ivy + plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it is not to important, if your build doesn't happen right away. So you can change the scheduling for checking your SCM. So lets say A will be triggered to check the SCM daily at midnight. Then configure B for checking daily at 2am (depending on the build times for A) and C 2 hours later. Since you will have artifacts for A and B, C will build fine. For newly created jobs, you will have artifacts as well, since you need to test your configuration, you just trigger the first build manually.

If that is not an option, you can always build all 3 of them. Meaning you create job D which contains the build instructions for A, B and C. This job will be triggered by changes to A, B, or C.